# How to fill up an input field with data from state?

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a simpler version of autocorrect where a user is able to select suggested sentences that come in from an API call based on the words they type in the `Description` field.

The user has the option to select the autocompleted sentence they want and that gets stored in state under `selectedDescription`.

My issue is taking those sentences from `selectedDescription` and filling them up in the input field `Description`.

The sentences that the user picks are stored in state

```
const [selectedDescription, setSelectedDescription] = useState();
```

`Input field where I want the data to be shown after the user selects a sentence`

```
<Input
  fluid
  placeholder="Description"
  value={description}
  onChange={(e) =>
    dispatch({
      type: "field",
      field: "description",
      value: e.currentTarget.value,
    })
  }
/>
```

I am not sure how to implement this as the description field is also used for setting the state for making the API request and I am worried the two will get mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just for idea you can implement in code like

```
const [selectedDescription, setSelectedDescription] = useState(undefined);


<Input
  fluid
  placeholder="Description"
  value={ selectedDescription || description}
  onChange={(e) => 
    if( selectedDescription === undefined || selectedDescription !== e.currentTarget.value ) {
    dispatch({
      type: "field",
      field: "description",
      value: e.currentTarget.value,
    })
   }
  }
/>
```